# How to Create a Custom Less Theme with the React Rsuite Library

Tags: reactjs

Has anyone used the Rsuite library (https://rsuitejs.com/en/guide/themes). I'm trying to create a custom theme but am having trouble following their instructions. I installed the following dependencies: customize-cra, less, less-loader, react-app-rewire-less, and react-app-rewired. Also, I'm not sure where to Import the default and custom .less files:

> Import less
>   Create a separate .less file as follows, and then introduce this file.

```
@import '~rsuite/styles/less/index.less'; //The default style file.
@import 'custom-theme.less'; // Style customization.
```

So far, my config.override.js looks like:

```
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
    fixBabelImports("babel-plugin-import", {
        libraryName: 'rsuite',
        libraryDirectory: 'styles',
        style: true
    }),
    addLessLoader({
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        importLoaders: true,
    })
);
```

The fixBabelImports is difficult for me because I keep getting this error when trying to compile:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'rsuite/styles/dropdown' in '/Users/kristenbaldwin/mreb-2/src/components/Navigation'

Here is my Navigation component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Sidenav, Toggle, Nav, Dropdown, Icon } from 'rsuite';
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import 'rsuite/styles/less/index.less';
import '../../styles/custom-theme.less';
import './Navigation.less';

const NoMatch = ({ location }) => (
    <div>
        <h3>Page not found: {location.pathname}</h3>
    </div>
);

class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            expanded: true,
            activeKey: '1',
        };
        this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    }
    handleToggle() {
        this.setState({
            expanded: !this.state.expanded
        });
    }
    handleSelect(eventKey) {
        this.setState({
            activeKey: eventKey
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { expanded } = this.state;
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="sidenav-wrapper">
                    <Sidenav expanded={expanded} appearance="inverse"
                        activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                        <Sidenav.Body>
                            <Toggle onChange={this.handleToggle} checked={expanded} />
                            <hr />
                            <Nav>
                                <Nav.Item componentClass={NavLink} to="/" eventKey="1" activeClassName="rs-nav-item-active" icon={<Icon icon="dashboard" />}>
                                    Dashboard
                                </Nav.Item>
                                <Nav.Item componentClass={NavLink} to="/agents" eventKey="2" activeClassName="rs-nav-item-active" icon={<Icon icon="group" />}>
                                    Agents
                                </Nav.Item>
                                <Dropdown placement="rightTop" eventKey="3" title="Advanced" icon={<Icon icon="magic" />}>
                                    <Dropdown.Item componentClass={NavLink} to="/geo" eventKey="3-1" activeClassName="rs-dropdown-item-active">Geo</Dropdown.Item>
                                    <Dropdown.Item componentClass={NavLink} to="/devices" eventKey="3-2" activeClassName="rs-dropdown-item-active">Devices</Dropdown.Item>
                                </Dropdown>
                                <Dropdown eventKey="4" title="Settings" icon={<Icon icon="gear-circle" />}>
                                    <Dropdown.Item componentClass={NavLink} to="/applications" eventKey="4-1" activeClassName="rs-dropdown-item-active">Applications</Dropdown.Item>
                                    <Dropdown.Item componentClass={NavLink} to="/channels" eventKey="4-2" activeClassName="rs-dropdown-item-active">Channels</Dropdown.Item>
                                </Dropdown>
                            </Nav>
                        </Sidenav.Body>
                    </Sidenav>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route component={NoMatch} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

If there are any examples of people using Rsuite and making custom themes, they would be super helpful to see! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the creators of the library take a look and with the update to react-app-rewired, you need to install customize-cra, less and less-loader. The config-overrides.js should be:

```
/* config-overrides.js */
const { override, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: { '@base-color': '#f44336' }
  })
);
```